# Converting a Future<void> into RxJava Observable or Flowable

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-workmanager

**How do I convert a future returning void into an RxJava Flowable or Observable?**

I am using RxJava and AndroidX WorkManager which provides an API which returns a `Future<void>`. I understand RxJava does not handle null values and will NullPointerException immediately. I am using `Flowable.fromFuture(resultFuture)`, where resultFuture is `Future<Void>` (specifically `ListenableFuture<Void>`), but since it returns Null, it crashes the app.

**Motivation:** I want to turn this future into a Rx observable/ flowable so that I can do processing after this future completes.

```kotlin
        return Flowable.fromFuture(futureReturningVoid)
                .flatMap { Flowable.fromIterable(files) }
                ...more processing here...
```

I need to return a `Single` at the end, so I cannot move the work into a listener, with `Future.addListener`.

---

I need flowable because I am dealing with processing of multiple input files, and want the backpressure to prevent opening too many files at once. I included Observable in case people have less complex requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So why not :

```
return Completable.fromFuture(futureReturningVoid)
            .andThen(Flowable.fromIterable(files))
```

Which is basically :

```
return Completable.fromAction { futureReturningVoid.get() }
            .andThen(Flowable.fromIterable(files))
```

Comment: I learnt about 3 different fundamental things in this answer (Use `get` instead of `wait` , `Completable`, and `andThen`. That was jam packed, thanks :)